# Query two tables with result opposite of join like statement

Tags: mysql

Here is the simple question to gain some medals :) :
I have three tables:
"contacts" that holds the contacts information where each entry has a unique id.
The second table "groups" where is stores the name for each group and the group id.
The last "contacts_groups" binds each contact to a group, it has just two columns, contact_id and group_id.

The question is how do write in a single statement a MySQL query that will select all contacts that are not assigned to a group. In other words contacts which id is not listed in "contacts_groups" table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from contacts c
left outer join contacts_groups cg on c.id = cg.contact_id 
where cg.contact_id is null
```

Comment: Column 'contact_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM contacts c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM contacts_groups cg
                  WHERE cg.contact_id = c.contact_id)
```

Comment: Cheers! from all three methods this was the fastest one.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be complete, here's another solution:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts
WHERE contact_id NOT IN (SELECT contact_id FROM contacts_groups)
```

However, I think MySQL tends to execute the left join or correlated subquery more efficiently.