# Select teachers which are available on a particular day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a teachers table with following fields

```
id  |  name
----------------
1   |  Teacher 1
2   |  Teacher 2
3   |  Teacher 3
----------------
```

Another table with the name available

```
id  |  teacher_id  | date
-------------------------------
1   |  2           | 2014-04-23
2   |  3           | 2014-04-22
-------------------------------
```

Students can search whether a teacher is available on a given day using the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM teachers, available
WHERE available.teacher_id = teachers.id
AND available.date =  "2014-04-23"
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Till now everything is fine.

Now the change is : by default a teacher will be available all days. So, the available table starts storing only the dates on which a particular teacher is not available.

Now the issue is using the following query, I am able to get the teachers who are available on a particular day if they have any entry in the availability table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM teachers, available
WHERE available.teacher_id = teachers.id
AND available.date !=  "2014-04-23"
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

As the Teacher 1 doesn't have an entry in the availability table, and as by default all teachers are available all days, i am not able to list him/her using the above query.

Could somebody please help me how to approach a solution for this?

Comment: Google Left or Right Outer Join

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query two tables with result opposite of join like statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131110/query-two-tables-with-result-opposite-of-join-like-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT techers.*
FROM
  teachers LEFT JOIN available
  ON teachers.id = available.teacher_id
     AND avaliable.date = '2014-04-23'
WHERE
  available.teacher_id IS NULL
```

this will return all teachers that have no record in the available table with the date given.

Please see this link about [ANTI JOIN](http://blog.montmere.com/2010/12/08/the-anti-join-all-values-from-table1-where-not-in-table2/) (all values from table1 that are not in table2).

Or you can use NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
FROM   teachers
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM   available
              WHERE  teachers.id = available.teacher_id
                     AND available.date = '2014-04-23')
```